# I tired to do something with JpaRepository But Can not find row with findById ,

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have tried to get  row by id with `findById` method but it it not succeed
 can't find row in DB .  and  when I call `findAll` before `findById` it's work fine. 
I use PostgreSQL.

```
public void updateOffer(OrderOfferDTO orderOfferDTO) {

  //        List<OrderOfferEntity> all = orderOfferRepository.findAll();
        OrderOfferEntity orderOfferEntity = orderOfferRepository.findById(orderOfferDTO.getId()).orElse(null);

        assert(orderOfferEntity != null);

        if (!isCanOfferUpdate(orderOfferEntity)) return;

        orderOfferEntity.setNumberOffer(orderOfferEntity.getNumberOffer() + 1);
        orderOfferEntity.setOfferDelivery(orderOfferDTO.getOfferDelivery());
        orderOfferEntity.setOfferPickup(orderOfferDTO.getOfferPickup());

        orderOfferRepository.save(orderOfferEntity);
    }
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface OrderOfferRepository extends JpaRepository<OrderOfferEntity, Long> {
    OrderOfferEntity findByUserEntityAndOrderEntity(UserEntity userEntity, OrderEntity orderEntity);

    List<OrderOfferEntity> findByUserEntityNotAndOrderEntity(UserEntity supplierEntity, OrderEntity orderEntity);
    List<OrderOfferEntity> findByOrderEntity(OrderEntity orderEntity);
    List<OrderOfferEntity> findByUserEntity(UserEntity userEntity);
}
```

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AUCTION_SUPPLIER")
@Data
public class OrderOfferEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NUMBER_OFFER")
    private Integer numberOffer;

    @Column(name = "OFFER_PICKUP")
    private Integer offerPickup;

    @Column(name = "OFFER_DELIVERY")
    private Integer offerDelivery;

    @Column(name = "IS_ACCEPTED")
    private Boolean isAccepted;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DELIVERY_PROGRESS_ID")
    private DeliveryProgressEntity deliveryProgressEntity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SUPPLIER_ID", nullable = false)
    private UserEntity userEntity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ORDER_ID", nullable = false)
    private OrderEntity orderEntity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FACTORY_ID", nullable = false)
    private FactoryEntity factoryEntity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FORMULA_ID", nullable = false)
    private FormulaEntity formulaEntity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PACKING_ID", nullable = false)
    private PackingEntity packingEntity;

}
```

Generated SQL

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        orderoffer0_.id as id1_1_0_,
        orderoffer0_.delivery_progress_id as delivery6_1_0_,
        orderoffer0_.factory_id as factory_7_1_0_,
        orderoffer0_.formula_id as formula_8_1_0_,
        orderoffer0_.is_accepted as is_accep2_1_0_,
        orderoffer0_.number_offer as number_o3_1_0_,
        orderoffer0_.offer_delivery as offer_de4_1_0_,
        orderoffer0_.offer_pickup as offer_pi5_1_0_,
        orderoffer0_.customer_order_id as customer9_1_0_,
        orderoffer0_.packing_id as packing10_1_0_,
        orderoffer0_.supplier_id as supplie11_1_0_,
        deliverypr1_.id as id1_6_1_,
        deliverypr1_.is_pickup as is_picku2_6_1_,
        deliverypr1_.name_progress as name_pro3_6_1_,
        deliverypr1_.progress_position as progress4_6_1_,
        factoryent2_.id as id1_7_2_,
        factoryent2_.address as address2_7_2_,
        factoryent2_.name as name3_7_2_,
        formulaent3_.id as id1_13_3_,
        formulaent3_.name as name2_13_3_,
        orderentit4_.id as id1_5_4_,
        orderentit4_.auction_progress_id as auction_9_5_4_,
        orderentit4_.end_datetime_auction as end_date2_5_4_,
        orderentit4_.end_datetime_auction_step as end_date3_5_4_,
        orderentit4_.max_date as max_date4_5_4_,
        orderentit4_.card_delivery_id as card_de10_5_4_,
        orderentit4_.fertilizer_id as fertili11_5_4_,
        orderentit4_.is_active as is_activ5_5_4_,
        orderentit4_.is_delivery as is_deliv6_5_4_,
        orderentit4_.is_pickup as is_picku7_5_4_,
        orderentit4_.card_pickup_id as card_pi12_5_4_,
        orderentit4_.customer_id as custome13_5_4_,
        orderentit4_.volume_fertilizer as volume_f8_5_4_,
        auctionpro5_.id as id1_0_5_,
        auctionpro5_.hours_on_progress as hours_on2_0_5_,
        auctionpro5_.is_end_auction as is_end_a3_0_5_,
        auctionpro5_.is_final_step as is_final4_0_5_,
        auctionpro5_.name_progress as name_pro5_0_5_,
        deliveryma6_.id as id1_3_6_,
        deliveryma6_.address as address2_3_6_,
        deliveryma6_.customer_id as customer3_3_6_,
        userentity7_.id as id1_20_7_,
        userentity7_.active as active2_20_7_,
        userentity7_.bank_id as bank_id11_20_7_,
        userentity7_.business_address as business3_20_7_,
        userentity7_.company_name as company_4_20_7_,
        userentity7_.email as email5_20_7_,
        userentity7_.inn as inn6_20_7_,
        userentity7_.kpp as kpp7_20_7_,
        userentity7_.ogrn as ogrn8_20_7_,
        userentity7_.password as password9_20_7_,
        userentity7_.phone_number as phone_n10_20_7_,
        userentity7_.role_id as role_id12_20_7_,
        bankentity8_.id as id1_2_8_,
        bankentity8_.account as account2_2_8_,
        bankentity8_.bic as bic3_2_8_,
        bankentity8_.name as name4_2_8_,
        roleentity9_.id as id1_21_9_,
        roleentity9_.name_role as name_rol2_21_9_,
        fertilizer10_.id as id1_9_10_,
        fertilizer10_.name as name2_9_10_,
        pickupmape11_.id as id1_4_11_,
        pickupmape11_.center_address as center_a2_4_11_,
        pickupmape11_.radius_value as radius_v3_4_11_,
        pickupmape11_.customer_id as customer4_4_11_,
        userentity12_.id as id1_20_12_,
        userentity12_.active as active2_20_12_,
        userentity12_.bank_id as bank_id11_20_12_,
        userentity12_.business_address as business3_20_12_,
        userentity12_.company_name as company_4_20_12_,
        userentity12_.email as email5_20_12_,
        userentity12_.inn as inn6_20_12_,
        userentity12_.kpp as kpp7_20_12_,
        userentity12_.ogrn as ogrn8_20_12_,
        userentity12_.password as password9_20_12_,
        userentity12_.phone_number as phone_n10_20_12_,
        userentity12_.role_id as role_id12_20_12_,
        userentity13_.id as id1_20_13_,
        userentity13_.active as active2_20_13_,
        userentity13_.bank_id as bank_id11_20_13_,
        userentity13_.business_address as business3_20_13_,
        userentity13_.company_name as company_4_20_13_,
        userentity13_.email as email5_20_13_,
        userentity13_.inn as inn6_20_13_,
        userentity13_.kpp as kpp7_20_13_,
        userentity13_.ogrn as ogrn8_20_13_,
        userentity13_.password as password9_20_13_,
        userentity13_.phone_number as phone_n10_20_13_,
        userentity13_.role_id as role_id12_20_13_,
        packingent14_.id as id1_19_14_,
        packingent14_.name as name2_19_14_,
        userentity15_.id as id1_20_15_,
        userentity15_.active as active2_20_15_,
        userentity15_.bank_id as bank_id11_20_15_,
        userentity15_.business_address as business3_20_15_,
        userentity15_.company_name as company_4_20_15_,
        userentity15_.email as email5_20_15_,
        userentity15_.inn as inn6_20_15_,
        userentity15_.kpp as kpp7_20_15_,
        userentity15_.ogrn as ogrn8_20_15_,
        userentity15_.password as password9_20_15_,
        userentity15_.phone_number as phone_n10_20_15_,
        userentity15_.role_id as role_id12_20_15_ 
    from
        auction_supplier orderoffer0_ 
    inner join
        delivery_progress deliverypr1_ 
            on orderoffer0_.delivery_progress_id=deliverypr1_.id 
    inner join
        factory factoryent2_ 
            on orderoffer0_.factory_id=factoryent2_.id 
    inner join
        formula formulaent3_ 
            on orderoffer0_.formula_id=formulaent3_.id 
    inner join
        customer_order orderentit4_ 
            on orderoffer0_.customer_order_id=orderentit4_.id 
    left outer join
        auction_progress auctionpro5_ 
            on orderentit4_.auction_progress_id=auctionpro5_.id 
    left outer join
        card_delivery deliveryma6_ 
            on orderentit4_.card_delivery_id=deliveryma6_.id 
    left outer join
        portal_user userentity7_ 
            on deliveryma6_.customer_id=userentity7_.id 
    left outer join
        bank bankentity8_ 
            on userentity7_.bank_id=bankentity8_.id 
    left outer join
        role roleentity9_ 
            on userentity7_.role_id=roleentity9_.id 
    inner join
        fertilizer fertilizer10_ 
            on orderentit4_.fertilizer_id=fertilizer10_.id 
    left outer join
        card_pickup pickupmape11_ 
            on orderentit4_.card_pickup_id=pickupmape11_.id 
    left outer join
        portal_user userentity12_ 
            on pickupmape11_.customer_id=userentity12_.id 
    inner join
        portal_user userentity13_ 
            on orderentit4_.customer_id=userentity13_.id 
    inner join
        packing packingent14_ 
            on orderoffer0_.packing_id=packingent14_.id 
    inner join
        portal_user userentity15_ 
            on orderoffer0_.supplier_id=userentity15_.id 
    where
        orderoffer0_.id=?
```

This generated SQL when I use findAll before findByID

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        orderoffer0_.id as id1_1_,
        orderoffer0_.delivery_progress_id as delivery6_1_,
        orderoffer0_.factory_id as factory_7_1_,
        orderoffer0_.formula_id as formula_8_1_,
        orderoffer0_.is_accepted as is_accep2_1_,
        orderoffer0_.number_offer as number_o3_1_,
        orderoffer0_.offer_delivery as offer_de4_1_,
        orderoffer0_.offer_pickup as offer_pi5_1_,
        orderoffer0_.customer_order_id as customer9_1_,
        orderoffer0_.packing_id as packing10_1_,
        orderoffer0_.supplier_id as supplie11_1_ 
    from
        auction_supplier orderoffer0_
Hibernate: 
    select
        factoryent0_.id as id1_7_0_,
        factoryent0_.address as address2_7_0_,
        factoryent0_.name as name3_7_0_ 
    from
        factory factoryent0_ 
    where
        factoryent0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        formulaent0_.id as id1_13_0_,
        formulaent0_.name as name2_13_0_ 
    from
        formula formulaent0_ 
    where
        formulaent0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        orderentit0_.id as id1_5_0_,
        orderentit0_.auction_progress_id as auction_9_5_0_,
        orderentit0_.end_datetime_auction as end_date2_5_0_,
        orderentit0_.end_datetime_auction_step as end_date3_5_0_,
        orderentit0_.max_date as max_date4_5_0_,
        orderentit0_.card_delivery_id as card_de10_5_0_,
        orderentit0_.fertilizer_id as fertili11_5_0_,
        orderentit0_.is_active as is_activ5_5_0_,
        orderentit0_.is_delivery as is_deliv6_5_0_,
        orderentit0_.is_pickup as is_picku7_5_0_,
        orderentit0_.card_pickup_id as card_pi12_5_0_,
        orderentit0_.customer_id as custome13_5_0_,
        orderentit0_.volume_fertilizer as volume_f8_5_0_,
        auctionpro1_.id as id1_0_1_,
        auctionpro1_.hours_on_progress as hours_on2_0_1_,
        auctionpro1_.is_end_auction as is_end_a3_0_1_,
        auctionpro1_.is_final_step as is_final4_0_1_,
        auctionpro1_.name_progress as name_pro5_0_1_,
        deliveryma2_.id as id1_3_2_,
        deliveryma2_.address as address2_3_2_,
        deliveryma2_.customer_id as customer3_3_2_,
        userentity3_.id as id1_20_3_,
        userentity3_.active as active2_20_3_,
        userentity3_.bank_id as bank_id11_20_3_,
        userentity3_.business_address as business3_20_3_,
        userentity3_.company_name as company_4_20_3_,
        userentity3_.email as email5_20_3_,
        userentity3_.inn as inn6_20_3_,
        userentity3_.kpp as kpp7_20_3_,
        userentity3_.ogrn as ogrn8_20_3_,
        userentity3_.password as password9_20_3_,
        userentity3_.phone_number as phone_n10_20_3_,
        userentity3_.role_id as role_id12_20_3_,
        bankentity4_.id as id1_2_4_,
        bankentity4_.account as account2_2_4_,
        bankentity4_.bic as bic3_2_4_,
        bankentity4_.name as name4_2_4_,
        roleentity5_.id as id1_21_5_,
        roleentity5_.name_role as name_rol2_21_5_,
        fertilizer6_.id as id1_9_6_,
        fertilizer6_.name as name2_9_6_,
        pickupmape7_.id as id1_4_7_,
        pickupmape7_.center_address as center_a2_4_7_,
        pickupmape7_.radius_value as radius_v3_4_7_,
        pickupmape7_.customer_id as customer4_4_7_,
        userentity8_.id as id1_20_8_,
        userentity8_.active as active2_20_8_,
        userentity8_.bank_id as bank_id11_20_8_,
        userentity8_.business_address as business3_20_8_,
        userentity8_.company_name as company_4_20_8_,
        userentity8_.email as email5_20_8_,
        userentity8_.inn as inn6_20_8_,
        userentity8_.kpp as kpp7_20_8_,
        userentity8_.ogrn as ogrn8_20_8_,
        userentity8_.password as password9_20_8_,
        userentity8_.phone_number as phone_n10_20_8_,
        userentity8_.role_id as role_id12_20_8_,
        userentity9_.id as id1_20_9_,
        userentity9_.active as active2_20_9_,
        userentity9_.bank_id as bank_id11_20_9_,
        userentity9_.business_address as business3_20_9_,
        userentity9_.company_name as company_4_20_9_,
        userentity9_.email as email5_20_9_,
        userentity9_.inn as inn6_20_9_,
        userentity9_.kpp as kpp7_20_9_,
        userentity9_.ogrn as ogrn8_20_9_,
        userentity9_.password as password9_20_9_,
        userentity9_.phone_number as phone_n10_20_9_,
        userentity9_.role_id as role_id12_20_9_ 
    from
        customer_order orderentit0_ 
    left outer join
        auction_progress auctionpro1_ 
            on orderentit0_.auction_progress_id=auctionpro1_.id 
    left outer join
        card_delivery deliveryma2_ 
            on orderentit0_.card_delivery_id=deliveryma2_.id 
    left outer join
        portal_user userentity3_ 
            on deliveryma2_.customer_id=userentity3_.id 
    left outer join
        bank bankentity4_ 
            on userentity3_.bank_id=bankentity4_.id 
    left outer join
        role roleentity5_ 
            on userentity3_.role_id=roleentity5_.id 
    inner join
        fertilizer fertilizer6_ 
            on orderentit0_.fertilizer_id=fertilizer6_.id 
    left outer join
        card_pickup pickupmape7_ 
            on orderentit0_.card_pickup_id=pickupmape7_.id 
    left outer join
        portal_user userentity8_ 
            on pickupmape7_.customer_id=userentity8_.id 
    inner join
        portal_user userentity9_ 
            on orderentit0_.customer_id=userentity9_.id 
    where
        orderentit0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        bankentity0_.id as id1_2_0_,
        bankentity0_.account as account2_2_0_,
        bankentity0_.bic as bic3_2_0_,
        bankentity0_.name as name4_2_0_ 
    from
        bank bankentity0_ 
    where
        bankentity0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        roleentity0_.id as id1_21_0_,
        roleentity0_.name_role as name_rol2_21_0_ 
    from
        role roleentity0_ 
    where
        roleentity0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        packingent0_.id as id1_19_0_,
        packingent0_.name as name2_19_0_ 
    from
        packing packingent0_ 
    where
        packingent0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        userentity0_.id as id1_20_0_,
        userentity0_.active as active2_20_0_,
        userentity0_.bank_id as bank_id11_20_0_,
        userentity0_.business_address as business3_20_0_,
        userentity0_.company_name as company_4_20_0_,
        userentity0_.email as email5_20_0_,
        userentity0_.inn as inn6_20_0_,
        userentity0_.kpp as kpp7_20_0_,
        userentity0_.ogrn as ogrn8_20_0_,
        userentity0_.password as password9_20_0_,
        userentity0_.phone_number as phone_n10_20_0_,
        userentity0_.role_id as role_id12_20_0_,
        bankentity1_.id as id1_2_1_,
        bankentity1_.account as account2_2_1_,
        bankentity1_.bic as bic3_2_1_,
        bankentity1_.name as name4_2_1_,
        roleentity2_.id as id1_21_2_,
        roleentity2_.name_role as name_rol2_21_2_ 
    from
        portal_user userentity0_ 
    inner join
        bank bankentity1_ 
            on userentity0_.bank_id=bankentity1_.id 
    inner join
        role roleentity2_ 
            on userentity0_.role_id=roleentity2_.id 
    where
        userentity0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    update
        auction_supplier 
    set
        delivery_progress_id=?,
        factory_id=?,
        formula_id=?,
        is_accepted=?,
        number_offer=?,
        offer_delivery=?,
        offer_pickup=?,
        customer_order_id=?,
        packing_id=?,
        supplier_id=? 
    where
        id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        userentity0_.id as id1_20_,
        userentity0_.active as active2_20_,
        userentity0_.bank_id as bank_id11_20_,
        userentity0_.business_address as business3_20_,
        userentity0_.company_name as company_4_20_,
        userentity0_.email as email5_20_,
        userentity0_.inn as inn6_20_,
        userentity0_.kpp as kpp7_20_,
        userentity0_.ogrn as ogrn8_20_,
        userentity0_.password as password9_20_,
        userentity0_.phone_number as phone_n10_20_,
        userentity0_.role_id as role_id12_20_ 
    from
        portal_user userentity0_ 
    where
        userentity0_.inn=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        bankentity0_.id as id1_2_0_,
        bankentity0_.account as account2_2_0_,
        bankentity0_.bic as bic3_2_0_,
        bankentity0_.name as name4_2_0_ 
    from
        bank bankentity0_ 
    where
        bankentity0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        roleentity0_.id as id1_21_0_,
        roleentity0_.name_role as name_rol2_21_0_ 
    from
        role roleentity0_ 
    where
        roleentity0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        userentity0_.id as id1_20_,
        userentity0_.active as active2_20_,
        userentity0_.bank_id as bank_id11_20_,
        userentity0_.business_address as business3_20_,
        userentity0_.company_name as company_4_20_,
        userentity0_.email as email5_20_,
        userentity0_.inn as inn6_20_,
        userentity0_.kpp as kpp7_20_,
        userentity0_.ogrn as ogrn8_20_,
        userentity0_.password as password9_20_,
        userentity0_.phone_number as phone_n10_20_,
        userentity0_.role_id as role_id12_20_ 
    from
        portal_user userentity0_ 
    where
        userentity0_.inn=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        bankentity0_.id as id1_2_0_,
        bankentity0_.account as account2_2_0_,
        bankentity0_.bic as bic3_2_0_,
        bankentity0_.name as name4_2_0_ 
    from
        bank bankentity0_ 
    where
        bankentity0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        roleentity0_.id as id1_21_0_,
        roleentity0_.name_role as name_rol2_21_0_ 
    from
        role roleentity0_ 
    where
        roleentity0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        orderentit0_.id as id1_5_0_,
        orderentit0_.auction_progress_id as auction_9_5_0_,
        orderentit0_.end_datetime_auction as end_date2_5_0_,
        orderentit0_.end_datetime_auction_step as end_date3_5_0_,
        orderentit0_.max_date as max_date4_5_0_,
        orderentit0_.card_delivery_id as card_de10_5_0_,
        orderentit0_.fertilizer_id as fertili11_5_0_,
        orderentit0_.is_active as is_activ5_5_0_,
        orderentit0_.is_delivery as is_deliv6_5_0_,
        orderentit0_.is_pickup as is_picku7_5_0_,
        orderentit0_.card_pickup_id as card_pi12_5_0_,
        orderentit0_.customer_id as custome13_5_0_,
        orderentit0_.volume_fertilizer as volume_f8_5_0_,
        auctionpro1_.id as id1_0_1_,
        auctionpro1_.hours_on_progress as hours_on2_0_1_,
        auctionpro1_.is_end_auction as is_end_a3_0_1_,
        auctionpro1_.is_final_step as is_final4_0_1_,
        auctionpro1_.name_progress as name_pro5_0_1_,
        deliveryma2_.id as id1_3_2_,
        deliveryma2_.address as address2_3_2_,
        deliveryma2_.customer_id as customer3_3_2_,
        userentity3_.id as id1_20_3_,
        userentity3_.active as active2_20_3_,
        userentity3_.bank_id as bank_id11_20_3_,
        userentity3_.business_address as business3_20_3_,
        userentity3_.company_name as company_4_20_3_,
        userentity3_.email as email5_20_3_,
        userentity3_.inn as inn6_20_3_,
        userentity3_.kpp as kpp7_20_3_,
        userentity3_.ogrn as ogrn8_20_3_,
        userentity3_.password as password9_20_3_,
        userentity3_.phone_number as phone_n10_20_3_,
        userentity3_.role_id as role_id12_20_3_,
        bankentity4_.id as id1_2_4_,
        bankentity4_.account as account2_2_4_,
        bankentity4_.bic as bic3_2_4_,
        bankentity4_.name as name4_2_4_,
        roleentity5_.id as id1_21_5_,
        roleentity5_.name_role as name_rol2_21_5_,
        fertilizer6_.id as id1_9_6_,
        fertilizer6_.name as name2_9_6_,
        pickupmape7_.id as id1_4_7_,
        pickupmape7_.center_address as center_a2_4_7_,
        pickupmape7_.radius_value as radius_v3_4_7_,
        pickupmape7_.customer_id as customer4_4_7_,
        userentity8_.id as id1_20_8_,
        userentity8_.active as active2_20_8_,
        userentity8_.bank_id as bank_id11_20_8_,
        userentity8_.business_address as business3_20_8_,
        userentity8_.company_name as company_4_20_8_,
        userentity8_.email as email5_20_8_,
        userentity8_.inn as inn6_20_8_,
        userentity8_.kpp as kpp7_20_8_,
        userentity8_.ogrn as ogrn8_20_8_,
        userentity8_.password as password9_20_8_,
        userentity8_.phone_number as phone_n10_20_8_,
        userentity8_.role_id as role_id12_20_8_,
        userentity9_.id as id1_20_9_,
        userentity9_.active as active2_20_9_,
        userentity9_.bank_id as bank_id11_20_9_,
        userentity9_.business_address as business3_20_9_,
        userentity9_.company_name as company_4_20_9_,
        userentity9_.email as email5_20_9_,
        userentity9_.inn as inn6_20_9_,
        userentity9_.kpp as kpp7_20_9_,
        userentity9_.ogrn as ogrn8_20_9_,
        userentity9_.password as password9_20_9_,
        userentity9_.phone_number as phone_n10_20_9_,
        userentity9_.role_id as role_id12_20_9_ 
    from
        customer_order orderentit0_ 
    left outer join
        auction_progress auctionpro1_ 
            on orderentit0_.auction_progress_id=auctionpro1_.id 
    left outer join
        card_delivery deliveryma2_ 
            on orderentit0_.card_delivery_id=deliveryma2_.id 
    left outer join
        portal_user userentity3_ 
            on deliveryma2_.customer_id=userentity3_.id 
    left outer join
        bank bankentity4_ 
            on userentity3_.bank_id=bankentity4_.id 
    left outer join
        role roleentity5_ 
            on userentity3_.role_id=roleentity5_.id 
    inner join
        fertilizer fertilizer6_ 
            on orderentit0_.fertilizer_id=fertilizer6_.id 
    left outer join
        card_pickup pickupmape7_ 
            on orderentit0_.card_pickup_id=pickupmape7_.id 
    left outer join
        portal_user userentity8_ 
            on pickupmape7_.customer_id=userentity8_.id 
    inner join
        portal_user userentity9_ 
            on orderentit0_.customer_id=userentity9_.id 
    where
        orderentit0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        roleentity0_.id as id1_21_0_,
        roleentity0_.name_role as name_rol2_21_0_ 
    from
        role roleentity0_ 
    where
        roleentity0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        orderoffer0_.id as id1_1_,
        orderoffer0_.delivery_progress_id as delivery6_1_,
        orderoffer0_.factory_id as factory_7_1_,
        orderoffer0_.formula_id as formula_8_1_,
        orderoffer0_.is_accepted as is_accep2_1_,
        orderoffer0_.number_offer as number_o3_1_,
        orderoffer0_.offer_delivery as offer_de4_1_,
        orderoffer0_.offer_pickup as offer_pi5_1_,
        orderoffer0_.customer_order_id as customer9_1_,
        orderoffer0_.packing_id as packing10_1_,
        orderoffer0_.supplier_id as supplie11_1_ 
    from
        auction_supplier orderoffer0_ 
    where
        orderoffer0_.supplier_id=? 
        and orderoffer0_.customer_order_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        factoryent0_.id as id1_7_0_,
        factoryent0_.address as address2_7_0_,
        factoryent0_.name as name3_7_0_ 
    from
        factory factoryent0_ 
    where
        factoryent0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        formulaent0_.id as id1_13_0_,
        formulaent0_.name as name2_13_0_ 
    from
        formula formulaent0_ 
    where
        formulaent0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        packingent0_.id as id1_19_0_,
        packingent0_.name as name2_19_0_ 
    from
        packing packingent0_ 
    where
        packingent0_.id=?
```

Comment: Take a look at the generated SQL statements and please post it here

Comment: Added for question

Comment: I meant the SQL that is produced when calling findById

Comment: Sorry, updated question

Comment: It might be something simple: check whether the HQL parameter fed into the query is actually a valid id (since it was auto-generated).

Comment: are you sure that all of the ManyToOne relationships are there? If one if this is null then you get null as result because there are inner joins

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, yes, I forgot about it. Thank you. Can you add your answer?

Comment: This does not explain why it's finding the record if findAll is executed beforehand.... Might be something else.

Comment: @Alexander.Furer The query might be different with fine all. Can you check the query that is executed with findAll as well?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, I added it. You were right it was generated different query

Comment: I knew it :-) I added my answer and would appreciate if you could accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All your ManyToOne relationships are either non-optional or not-null.

So Hibernate generates INNER JOINS. You have to make sure that your data is following this rules.

If you define non-optional or not null relationships you should also have a NOT NULL constraint on the foreign key in the database table.