# spring data JPA - mysql - findById() empty unless findAll() called before

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm struggling with this strange error: the `findById()` method of a `CrudRepository` returns `Optional.empty`, unless `findAll()` is called before when using mysql.

e.g.

User

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

UserRepository

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, UUID> { }
```

UserService

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Transactional
    public UUID create() {
        final User user = new User();
        userRepository.save(user);
        return user.getId();
    }

    @Transactional
    public User find(@PathVariable UUID userId) {
        // userRepository.findAll(); TODO without this functin call, Optinoal.empty is returned by the repo
        return userRepository.findById(userId).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("missing user:%s", userId)));
    }
}
```

UserApp

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class UserApp {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserApp.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        final UUID userId = userService.create();
        final User user = userService.find(userId);
        LOG.info("found user: {}", user.getId());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_test
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database=mysql
```

Why does the `findAll()` method call change the result of `findById()`?

Edit: Hibernate logs with `findAll`:

```
Hibernate: drop table if exists user
Hibernate: create table user (id binary(255) not null, primary key (id)) engine=MyISAM
Hibernate: insert into user (id) values (?)
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_0_ from user user0_
```

Without:

```
Hibernate: drop table if exists user
Hibernate: create table user (id binary(255) not null, primary key (id)) engine=MyISAM
Hibernate: insert into user (id) values (?)
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_0_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.id=?
```

Comment: I can't give a definitive answer but it is probably related to Hibernates caching and the `findAll` triggering a flush. Could you post the SQL statements that get executed for both variants?

Comment: Logs attached to my question.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue. Did you find the solution to your problem? Thanks.

Comment: Hey Did you find the answer? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @MHogge Did you find the solution?

Comment: I didn't find a solution, switched to postgresql

Comment: Hi, unfortunately no. I went a few commits back and the error was gone but I never found the real cause. Sorry for the lack of help.

Answer (score 8):

As already written before (but more generically) after some tests my conclusion is that the issue occurs when there is a discrepancy of mandatory fields and database data in @ManyToOne relations. For example, imagine to have a table without constraints of mandatory fields, but at the same time your Hibernate model class with a @ManyToOne(optional = false) constraint. And imagine to populate the table (say with a SQL script), leaving the indicted field as *null*. When you will try to perform a *findById()*, a **deleteById** or whatever operation that **implies a get by Id** you will experience this (horrible) side effect.

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue. The root cause was the mismatch between non-nullable @ManyToOne relation and the data persisted in table.
I had this:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name="batch_id")
  private Batch batch;
```

which means batch_id can't be null in any row. However, my rows had null value for batch_id foreign key. After removing optional = false (which is the expected business rule), findById started working as expected.

Got indication from this thread: [I tired to do something with JpaRepository But Can not find row with findById ,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57691085/i-tired-to-do-something-with-jparepository-but-can-not-find-row-with-findbyid)

Comment: For me it was the same root cause! I had a `@JoinColumn(name = "voucher_id", nullable = false)` but persisted the entity with `null` value for the `voucher_id` column. After removing the non-null constraint, everything worked again as expected!

Comment: I would never find it if not for this answer!
This makes me very suspicious of JPA from now on.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use below code;

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
@Type(type="uuid-char")
private UUID id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the incorrect 'optional' mentioned in other answers, I have also had this when there was a `@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` annotation on an attribute that was, in fact, null within the database