# findById(id) is returning Null on first encounters but works after using findAll() method

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
   @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public Student findById(@PathVariable final int id) {
        Optional<Student> optionalStudent = studentJpaRepository.findById(id);
        return (optionalStudent.isPresent()) ? optionalStudent.get():null;
    }
```

I have debugged and saw an interesting result.
Unless i use studentJpaRepository.findAll() which returns list of students successfully,the studentJpaRepository.findById(id) is always returning Optional.empty.

Repository is

```
@Component
public interface StudentJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Integer>{

    Student findByLastname(String lastname);

}
```

But once use the studentJpaRepository.findAll() , the calls studentJpaRepository.findById(id) seem to be working fine. Its something like Db is sleeping and FindAll call activates it and then other calls also work.
Is this a cache issue?

Db used: MS SQL

Comment: No that cannot be possible. can you share more details about your code, which database  r u using? show your repository class

Comment: Could you add repository and whole controller?

Comment: I added the repository and the SQL is pf MS SQL server

Comment: How are you calling API. log the value of `id`

Comment: via postman.Its a simple get call with no headers..the id is getting logged correctly

Comment: I am having the same issue. Using spring version 2.2.6. Any progress?

Comment: Was having the same issue. Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61536691/5559928